# ERROR 000464 when trying to update domains

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, domains, schema-locks, error-000464

I have a python script which runs nightly to update a few domains in an Enterprise Geodatabase (Oracle). I'm using the **[arcpy.TableToDomain_management](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/table-to-domain.htm)** tool. The script works fine unless there are schema locks on the domain. In particular, if ArcMap is open with a layer that is using one of these domains, the script fails to update the domain.

The error returned is:

```
ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited or in use by another application.
Failed to execute (TableToDomain).
```

I have attempted to disconnect users, thinking that would work. The code to disconnect users is:

```
def dropUsers():
    userList = [user for user in arcpy.ListUsers(sde_workspace)]
    for user in userList:
        try:
            arcpy.DisconnectUser(sde_workspace, user.ID)
            print('Disconnecting user: {0}, userID: {1}.'.format(user.Name, user.ID))
        except Exception as e:
            print('Could not disconnect user: {0}, userID: {1}.'.format(user.Name, user.ID))
            print(e)
        finally:
            arcpy.AcceptConnections(sde_workspace, True)
```

`sde_workspace` in the above code is a path to a connection file using the sde account.

The code to actually update the domain is:

```
arcpy.TableToDomain_management(os.path.join(output_folder, '{}.csv'.format(workzone)),code_field='Code',description_field='Description',in_workspace=destination_workspace, domain_name=domain_name,update_option="REPLACE")
```

`destination_workspace` in the above code is a path to a connection file using the domain owner.

No matter what I try, I cannot update the domains. I should also add, that I tried the TableToDomain geoprocessing tool and got the same 000464 error. However, if I close ArcMap and ensure no one else has ArcMap open, *and* I don't disconnect users, it works fine.

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.

Comment: Do you have any map/feature services pulling from the database? If so you may have to stop those services before editing the domains.

Comment: I do, but they get disconnected. They were published without schema locks, so I was pretty sure they were not causing the lock. I figured it out and answered the question below.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this. It turns out that part of my script reads the domains which need to be updated. The reason for this is that I only update the domains if they have changed.

It turns out that reading the domains creates another connection. When I then drop all connections, ArcGIS must get confused and thinks it's still open.

The solution is to omit this connection when I drop users. To do this, I look at connection time and omit the most recently connected user.

I've modified my dropUsers function accordingly:

```
def dropUsers():
    userList = [user for user in arcpy.ListUsers(sde_workspace) if user.Name in ('AMIS', 'READONLY')]
    userList.sort(key = lambda user:user.ConnectionTime) #Don't drop most recently connected user - this may be the user that is running this script
    popped_user = userList.pop()
    print('Not disconnecting user: {0}, userID: {1}, Connected at {2}'.format(popped_user.Name, popped_user.ID, popped_user.ConnectionTime))

    for user in userList:
        try:
            arcpy.DisconnectUser(sde_workspace, user.ID)
            print('Disconnecting user: {0}, userID: {1}, Connected at {2}'.format(user.Name, user.ID, user.ConnectionTime))
            logging.warning('Disconnecting user: {0}, userID: {1}, Connected at {2}'.format(user.Name, user.ID, user.ConnectionTime))
        except Exception as e:
            print('Could not disconnect user: {0}, userID: {1}, Connected at {2}'.format(user.Name, user.ID, user.ConnectionTime))
            logging.error('Could not disconnect user: {0}, userID: {1}, Connected at {2}'.format(user.Name, user.ID, user.ConnectionTime))
            print(e)
            logging.error(e)
        finally:
            arcpy.AcceptConnections(sde_workspace, True)
```